# Chrome not displaying multiple uls inline

Tags: css

http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/2118/screenshotfrom201206151.png

I have a basic ul li ul li nested dropdown menu layout here, but I am encountering an odd error.

In the css, I have set

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Which should make:

```
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a>(home)
      </li>    
   </ul>    
   <ul>    
      (other <li>s)
   </ul>
```

Display as they do in firefox here, right?
With chrome, it does as pictured the vast majority of the time, but one in 20 refreshes or so will leave the menus inline.
It works in Opera as it does in firefox, so this makes me think that this is a webkit problem.

How exactly can I amend the code so that it behaves as in opera/firefox?

Comment: What is nav supposed to be? Can you provide the rest of your css/html?

Comment: nav is meant to be the <nav> element in html5.  

http://pastebin.com/jTat7nb8  <- Here is the CSS  

http://pastebin.com/mnJuf9zu  <- Here is the HTML

Comment: OK, just making sure. I don't see anything obvious yet. Can you link me the page? I'm on chromium now so I can confirm the idiosyncracy possibly.

Comment: http://59.167.203.219/blog/main.php

Comment: I can't reproduce anything unusual. What version of Chrome and what OS?

Comment: 19.0.1084.56-r120965 (chrome-stable in their official repository)

Ubuntu 12.04 x64

For you, it is displaying inline 100% of the time?

Comment: I refreshed it 20-30 times and I did not see any artifacts, but I'm at work on my Windows 7 machine. When I get home I will try with chromium on my Arch Linux box and report back to you (with version#) what results I had. (My Arch box is still 32-bit, though, so it's still not an exact replication.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can indeed confirm odd behavior (they appear below the nav) in chromium 19.0.1084.56-1 on Arch Linux that does not occur in, e.g., Opera 12. Furthermore, Inspect Element on both the nav and the li's and unticking their CSS properties one by one didn't ever fix it, so this may be a weird chromium bug that should be reported to them. Perhaps you could start a polite topic about this on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/chromium-dev)?

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion. I have placed a bug report in the official channels.

Comment: If they respond and solve it for you, please update the answer here. If it is indeed a confirmed bug, please update the question with a link to the bug report. :)